Dovecot and new email notifications
I have installed Dovecot on my Ubuntu 24.04 (arm64) recently.
Turns out it's not really for me, so I wanted to get rid of it from my system. I purged all related packages - I believe, but the login message "You have no new mail" stayed there.
It doesn't appear on new users, but it is quite annoying on my main account. I have no idea whatsoever how to remove it. Do you which package may be responsible for 'checking' for new emails on Ubuntu server login? Here is how it looks like:
EDIT: I solved the problem by installing postfix and dovecot-core and
apt purging them.

Could this be mutt? See if you have it, and maybe remove it.

No, mutt is not installed in the system.
